# Why does my PC restart itself every now and then when using Ubuntu?

Tags: crash, restart

I use Ubuntu 20.04. The PC frequently restarts itself when using the actual OS or the live flash drive. I don't think the issue is with overheating because when I use the sensors utility:

```
amdgpu-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:      768.00 mV
fan1:         709 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 3700 RPM)
edge:         +34.0°C  (crit = +94.0°C, hyst = -273.1°C)
power1:       30.14 W  (cap = 145.00 W)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +32.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +29.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +33.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +30.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

So I looked through the log files but couldn't find anything useful.

var/log/syslog: https://pastebin.com/JsM6zVmR

var/log/kern.log: https://pastebin.com/ym6PVD0u

Comment: Read `man journalctl` and use `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` to look at the logs of the last shutdown.

Comment: @user535733 its saying "Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP." right before restart

Comment: @waltinator the last line before restart is "Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP."

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @waltinator Sorry for that, also I updated the question.